# Cannot add task 'generateLockfiles' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle

I have a flutter app using firebase. I had some issues with running the app after importing all firebase-packages. I kinda solved it, but it seems like now I have another big issue.

Whenever I run my app, I get the following error:
"

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 177
- What went wrong:
  **A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Failed to apply plugin class 'FlutterPlugin'.
> Cannot add task 'generateLockfiles' as a task with that name already exists.**

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  "

I cannot find any *generateLockfiles *in my app's directory.

In flutter.groovy this is the only line where *generateLockfiles *occurs:
`@Override
void apply(Project project) {
this.project = project

```
    def rootProject = project.rootProject
    if (isFlutterAppProject()) {
        rootProject.tasks.register('generateLockfiles') {
            rootProject.subprojects.each { subproject ->
                def gradlew = (OperatingSystem.current().isWindows()) ?
                    "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradlew.bat" : "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradlew"
                rootProject.exec {
                    workingDir rootProject.projectDir
                    executable gradlew
                    args ":${subproject.name}:dependencies", "--write-locks"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}`

I tried:

- copying my lib to a new project
- flutter clean, flutter pub get
- finding generateLockfiles in my app's directory

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
Please try to update your Gradle by following these 2 commands in your Flutter project.

```
cd android
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=8.4
```

You can try latest version of Gradle. in my project, this version is working properly as of now.